# Rollback in NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, ndb

I am trying to maintain some cross transactional-ity between different services.

Basically I have a ndb model which would be processed. There is a chance that the transaction might fail after we have saved an object. How would I rollback in such a scenario?

Example

```
class PersonTable(ndb.Model):
    personId = ndb.StringProperty()
    personName = ndb.StringProperty()
    personAddress = ndb.StringProperty()
    personOldReference = ndb.StringProperty()
    scopeReference = ndb.StringProperty()

    def save():
          self.put()

def some_method(person_id, person_name):
     person = PersonTable.get(person_id)
     person.personName = person_name

     sql_db.saveRelated(person_id, personName)
     person.save()

@ndb.transactional
def outer_method(person_id, person_name):
    person_name = prefix+person_name
    some_method(person_id, person_name)
    post_update_tasks(person_id)
```

Now I was thinking of something like

```
def some_method(person_id, person_name):
     person = PersonTable.get(person_id)
     person.personName = person_name

     try:
         sql_db.saveRelated(person_id, personName)
         person.save()
     except Exception as e:
         sql_db.rollback(person_id)
         raise e
```

This would solve the problem if `save` fails. But if something fails in the `outer_method` after, then the transactional fails and ndb will roll back but `sql_db` would not be able to rollback.

```
@ndb.transactional
def outer_method(person_id, person_name):
    person_name = prefix+person_name
    some_method(person_id, person_name) ---> This is sucessfull & data is saved in both ndb & sql.
    post_update_tasks(person_id) --> If this fails then ndb is rolled back but not SQL.
```

How would I solve for this problem? Is there a hook on the model similar to `_pre_put_hook` which would execute if theres a rollback on ndb?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you just couldnt put the try-except-rollback around `outer_method`?

```
@ndb.transactional
def _outer_method(person_id, person_name):  # renamed outer_method to _outer_method
    person_name = prefix+person_name
    some_method(person_id, person_name)
    post_update_tasks(person_id)

def outer_method(person_id, person_name):
    try:
        _outer_method(person_id, person_name)
    except:
        sql_db.rollback(person_id)
```

Also, what does `post_update_tasks` do? does that launch tasks with appengine taskqueue? you're going to have to migrate to google-cloud-tasks at some point and that doesnt support transactions anymore.

> Is there a hook on the model similar to _pre_put_hook which would execute if theres a rollback on ndb?

I believe these are all the 'hooks' you have at your disposal:

https://github.com/googleapis/python-ndb/blob/921ec695e246e548f207b0c6aded7296e4b3b263/google/cloud/ndb/model.py#L6126

Comment: I cannot put around outer method. In the code we have a Business Object where these things are happening.  Over the codebase there are several places we have used that. Now it's not possible to put the try catch everywhere over a large codebase. And it's not reasonable to expect everyone in the large team to start using that pattern going forward.